# Android Widget Button Not Working

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, android-appwidget

The widget is only a textview and a button. When a user clicks on the button, the New activity is launched. My button somehow is not opening the New activity(basically a blank activity). Below are my codes.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.widget_ex;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;


public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider{
      @Override
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
            final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
              int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

              Intent intent = new Intent(context, New.class);
              PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

              RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
              views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent);

              appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            }
          }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**widgetprovider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:minWidth="146dp" 
   android:updatePeriodMillis="0" 
   android:minHeight="146dp" 
   android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_main">

</appwidget-provider>
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.widget_ex"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.widget_ex.New"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
         <receiver android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/widgetprovider" />
         </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**New.class**

```
package com.example.widget_ex;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class New extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.another);
    }

}
```

**another.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onUpdate() method is not called. You have to override the onUpdate() method.

Comment: thanks for the input. I changed my code to include @Override and still not working

Comment: then it could be more problem in code, i am looking

Comment: Are you seeing the button in widget? I don't see in the widget.

Comment: I changed the layout_height="100dp" and removed the android:layout_marginTop="19dp". now its working

Comment: widget height cannot be match_parent.

Comment: Ohh okay thanks! hmm...i can actually see the textview and button on my widget. Anyway, really appreciated your help! I will go test it now

Comment: Are you able to launch the activity when button clicked?

Comment: Iam able to launch the activity from widget button with your code.

Comment: hmm really?? I think i will relaunch my eclipse

Comment: can u post your New.class

Comment: I don't see any problem with New activity. Are you testing in device or emulator?

Comment: I am testing it on my android device (moto g). hmm...i probably hav a little typo somewhere when i was making changes to it. I think i will be fine now. Thanks!